Handling the .bss Section in Raw Binary Formats and Freestanding Environments
When working in a raw/freestanding environment, I have a question about the .bss section in ELF files. If I link and set the output format to binary (not ELF), where will the .bss section be in the final binary? Additionally, since the .bss section is typically initialized by a loader at runtime in ELF, would using global variables in my kernel cause issues in such an environment?

I must admit though if you have your own linker script, where the .bss is placed by the linker script can alter the behavior as to whether the .bss is put in a loadable part of the kernel or not.

I see you have a Gitbub repository here:  https://github.com/SafeMemoryZone/ssos . You have a linker script that puts the .bss section into an output section .data that also includes input section .data . The way you have done this means that the .bss data will become part of the binary itself and be added to the other non zero data. In this case all the .bss data will become art of the data and will be set to 0.

Unfortunately doing it the way you did can bloat the binary file if you have a lot of data in the .bss section. Had you placed .bss  in its own output section as the last section in link.ld then the .bss data would not be part of the binary and you'd have to initialize the .bss  memory area yourself before calling kmain.

I recommend not outputting directly to binary using a linker script. I'd default to outputting ELF file and then using i686-elf-objcopy to convert the ELF file to binary. The advantage of this method is you can use the ELF file for debug information (aids in debugging with GDB if you connect to something like QEMU remotely). The ELF file can be dumped with i686-elf-objdump -DxS that can tell you where in memory things are and could have answered your question about  where the BSS data was and whether it was pre-zeroed for you.

I have submitted a pull request here: https://github.com/SafeMemoryZone/ssos/pull/1 that you may find of use. It puts the .bss data in its own section. The .bss section won't bloat the size of kernel.bin. Modified _start to initialize the .bss section to 0. I also modified the link.ld to output as ELF instead of binary and used i686-elf-objcopy to convert it to binary. This can aid you if you use GDB to do remote debugging (with QEMU for example)
